# Efficient way to resize photos in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-graphics

What is the most efficient way to iterate over the entire camera roll, open every single photo and resize it?

My naive attempts to iterate over the asset library and get the `defaultRepresentation` results took about 1 second per 4 images (iPhone 5). Is there a way to do better?

I need the resized images to do some kind of processing.

Answer (score 0):

Resizing full resolution photos is rather expensive operation. But you can use images already resized to screen resolution:

```
ALAsset *result = // .. do not forget to initialize it
ALAssetRepresentation *rawImage = [result defaultRepresentation];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:rawImage.fullScreenImage];
```

If you need another resolution you can still use 'fullScreenImage' since it has smaller size than original photo.

> - (CGImageRef)fullScreenImage
>
> Returns a CGImage of the representation that is appropriate for
>   displaying full screen. The dimensions of the image are dependent on
>   the device your application is running on; the dimensions may not,
>   however, exactly match the dimensions of the screen.
>
> In iOS 5 and later, this method returns a fully cropped, rotated, and
>   adjusted image—exactly as a user would see in Photos or in the image
>   picker.
>
> Returns   a CGImage of the representation that is appropriate for
>   displaying full screen, or NULL if a CGImage representation could not
>   be generated.